# Populate RecyclerView using Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Good Evening.

I have a Test code in which I want to populate a RecycleView that has an ImageView.
The ImageView will be filled with a JPG image from an URL in Firebase Database.

The problem is that I don't get how to retrieve data and populate recycleview
I was reading FirebaseUI on Github but sincerely I find it somehow difficult because I'm alone in this application.

This is the MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{


    DatabaseReference mReference;
    DatabaseReference mURLReference;

    public FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Pictures, PicturesHolder> mRecyclerViewAdapter;
    //UI
    RecyclerView mImagesRV;
    LinearLayoutManager mManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        mReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mURLReference= mReference.child("Pictures Data");

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        mImagesRV=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        mManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mManager.setReverseLayout(false);

        mImagesRV.setHasFixedSize(false);
        mImagesRV.setLayoutManager(mManager);

    }

    public void onAttachRecyclerView()
    {

        Query lastHundred = mURLReference.limitToLast(100);
        mRecyclerViewAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Pictures, PicturesHolder>(
                Pictures.class,R.layout.content_main,PicturesHolder.class, lastHundred
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(PicturesHolder pictureView, Pictures pictures, int position) {


            }
        };
    }
}
```

This is the Object that I use to insert data in FirebaseDatabase (I just want the URL):

```
public class Pictures {


    String pictureID;
    String downloadURL;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    public Pictures() {

    }

    public void setPictureID(String pictureID) {
        this.pictureID = pictureID;
    }

    public void setDownloadURL(String downloadURL) {
        this.downloadURL = downloadURL;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getPictureID() {
        return pictureID;
    }

    public String getDownloadURL() {
        return downloadURL;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
}
```

And this is the ViewHolder, I don't know if it's okay..

```
public class PicturesHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView imageView;

    public PicturesHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.picture_view);

    }

    public void setImageView(ImageView imageView) {
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }
}
```

It would be nice to receive a good advise from you guys!
Thank you so much.

Comment: Well, I've never used firebase database but what are you using for networking? Because i can't see any.

Comment: First, you need to provide an implementation of populateViewHolder to copy data from the Picture into the PictureHolder views.  Second, you probably don't want a method to set views into the PictureHolder. ViewHolders only ever extract references to views found in the passed itemView.  Instead, you probably want to take the download url and use something like Glide to download the image and place it into the ImageView.  Lastly, if you're not familiar with how RecyclerView works, you might want to do a simple example first, without Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Glide to populate images in my RecyclerView. Given a String that is an HTTP URL, Glide will resolve the String and display the image residing at that HTTP address in your ImageView.

Here's a link to Glide:  https://github.com/bumptech/glide

You need to include Glide in your build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

In the ViewHolder create a method setImage() that uses Glide to set the image:

```
public static class PicturesHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    Context ctx;
    ImageView image;

    public PicturesHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        this.ctx = v.getContext();
        this.image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
    }

    public void setImage(String url) {
        Glide.with(ctx)
                .load(url)
                .into(image);
    }
}
```

Then in populateViewHolder you'll call the setImage() method from your viewholder and pass as an argument the return value of getDownloadURL() from your Pictures model:

```
@Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(PicturesHolder viewHolder, Pictures model, int position) {
        viewHolder.setImage(model.getDownloadURL());
}
```

Comment: It worked, you're an angel! Thank you thank you thank you!